# BufferedReader adding "," after each line. Facing issues while replacing commas with blanks

Tags: java

In the below code (i.e., in the 'filecontents' function), I am actually trying to open and read contents of a file.

Example: Input file contains ABCD EFGH

Within the try block, following lines of code are adding "," after each line

```
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
              content.add(line);
            }
            return content;
```

i.e, If the file has contents ABCD EFGH - The above piece of code is returning the output as ABCD, EFGH.

Is there any way that I can replace the comma with blanks (maybe) and send the string as ABCD EFGH to the calling function?

I tried different ways - ReplaceAll, Replace, List  to String, Stringbuffer etc but every try is leading to an error elsewhere.

Below is the sample code:

//Function 1

```
private static void read (String file)
{
String filename = "C:\Desktop\Sample.txt";
List<String> records = filecontents (filename);
}
```

//Above piece of code will be calling the following code below where the filename is passed as a parameter

```
private static List<String> filecontents(String file)
{

          List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
          try
          {
            //Open the text file
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));               
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
            content.add(line);
            }

            //return content;
            //Finding out a way to remove the commas and pass back the lines 
             (without commas) to the calling function
             reader.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            //Catch block
          }
    return null; 

}
```

Comment: How do you output your list? Are you just using `System.out.println(fileContents(...))`? Then the commas don't actually exist. They are there to separate different elements of the list.

Comment: Lets say, ABCD, EFGH is the content of that particular text file which Bufferedreader will read. This will then be returned to the calling function (but without the commas). It should replace the commas added by content.add(line) and send back only ABCD EFGH (Since this is the actual content of the file).

Comment: Do you also see extra `[` `]` at start and end? In that case take a look here: https://ideone.com/r2WvOd, As you see in that example we didn't add any commas, but they appear in console. Why? Because `toString()` method of `list` (which is invoked by `println` at some point) adds them as separator.

Comment: `content.add(line)` does _not_ add commas. Show me a [mcve].

Comment: @Sweeper I again tried content.add(line); followed by    System.out.println("Display:"+content); ---- It is actually adding commas

Comment: There we go. Try using a `for` loop to print each item in `content` on a separate line. Do you still see commas?

Comment: @Pshemo I am not seeing [ ]. Actually content.add(line) in the above code is adding "," after ABCD - So the output looks like ABCD,EFGH.

Comment: Strange, calling `toString()` (here implicitly) should return string representing list elements in form `[element1, element2, .., elementX]`. Anyway BufferedReader is class used for decade without that kind of problem. Unless you provide real [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) which will let us reproduce that problem it makes more sense to assume that it is not bug in that class, but rather it is bug *somewhere* in your code (in part which you may not be showing us). So without seeing such example we can't really help you beside guessing which is not efficient way to solving problems.

Comment: @Sweeper I just tried something like this outside try block -- for (String s : content)    System.out.println("content :"+ s); ... This is actually displaying as content: ABCD  and in the next line of console it displays content: EFGH. I am unable to do return s; here as it says 's cannot be resolved to a variable'

Comment: @Pshemo I have updated my post by adding the calling function complete code too as required.

Comment: Above example needs also part which generates output with commas, and exact content of `C:\Desktop\Sample.txt` you used while running it.

Comment: Also what you posted doesn't compile which suggests it is not example which even *you* could use to reproduce described problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The readline() of the BufferedReader does not add commas. It reads the string until it reaches a line separator like `\n` or `\r`.

What I'm guessing is happening is your ABCD and EFGH is in a list, as two separate elements, and what you're actually seeing in the printout is the comma separating those two elements.

Try creating a new text file and manually writing

```
ABCD EFGH
```

without copy and pasting. Your text file most likely contains hidden line separators that is messing up your buffered reader and separating the line.

Comment: Ah! I see. I manually typed it out and observed that it passes as ABCD EFGH to the calling function. I now need to figure out a way to remove such hidden line separators from notepad string. Thank you much for the solution.

Comment: I am unable to upvote as it says I need some reputation before I click on the upbutton. Request others who can, to do on my behalf. Thanks